# Simple Bitwise XOR query error

Tags: sql, t-sql, bit-manipulation

This is a first time I'm executing bitwise query and I get a problem that I do not understand. I have a Table1 with binary(128) ColumnA
I execute

```
select *
from Table1
where Table1.ColumnA ^ CAST(127 as binary(128)) <> 0
```

It should produce all records that have any of first 7 bits set to 1.
Instead I get this error

> The data types binary and binary are incompatible in the '^' operator.

So is the right way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both operands cannot be `binary`.  One, must be `int`, `tinyint` or `smallint`.  See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) for more info.

I would try just using `^ 127` instead:

```
select *
from Table1
where Table1.ColumnA ^ 127 <> 0
```